# store.CreateRecord push record to store even negative response from server

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have following function:

```
    this.store.createRecord('user', params).save().then(()=>{
      this.set('responseModal', 'Utworzono użytkownika!');
    })
```

And my question is: Why Ember push record to store before response from server?
For example: I'm filling form incorrectly, and my server return with error and status: 400, but my record without it's id-key is still in store. I tried something like this:

```
.catch(()=>{
      user.unloadRecord();
    });
```

But it looks bad, when something record display and instantly hide. Is something way to create record in store only after response from server without external libraries? I want to use only ember-data to connect client with the server. Any advice and suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form submission is not succeeded then we will give them another attempt with already user provided data. so we need to store the data in `store`. if you are navigating to some other page or don't want to give another attempt with old data then you can always use [rollbackAttributes](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollbackAttributes)

> If the model hasDirtyAttributes this function will discard any unsaved
>   changes. If the model isNew it will be removed from the store.

Comment: rollbackAttributes, it is what I need :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `unloadRecord` on the store instead and pass the object that didn't save correctly.

> ```
> .catch(()=>{
>   user.unloadRecord();
> });
> ```

I think this should work:

```
  //unloads the record from the store if save() fails.
  //This prevents any invalid records from being pushed into the store and viewable to user.
.catch(()=>{
  this.get('store').unloadRecord( {userObjectWithNullId} );
});
```

An alternative would be to use form validation. User won't be able to submit a form until the form is correct. Here's the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_handling-validation-errors) for that